# Setup Suse Enterprise SLES 12 from inside Opensuse on a VPS

Tags: vps, opensuse, sles

Is it possible to install SLES 12 from CLI on a VPS that already has Opensuse LEAP 42? knowing that there is no option from the hosting provider for LiveCD, network-setup nor a pre-installed image.

Answer (score -2):

You can install SLES 12 as a virtual machine on top of OpenSUSE using KVM.

Comment: That's not what OP asked.

Comment: Thanks but the purpose is to replace the current OpenSuse with SLES

Comment: Since there is no option for using a Live CD, network setup (PXE) og pre-insalled image, this is, as far as I can tell, the only anwer to the question. Or you could say that it can´t be done. You can´t replace OpenSUSE with SLES from within OpenSUSE.